# Sharepoint Add-in needs to call C# method

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to create a Sharepoint Add-In which calls a C# method when the Add-In page loads. I have tried calling the C# method from javascript, but that does not seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provider-hosted addin should work.

Comment: I am new to sharepoint can you give me some pointers on how to use Provider-hosted addins

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor's suggestion, if want to use C# code in SharePoint Add-in, it's necessary to use Provider Hosted Add-in Type rather than SharePoint hosted Add-in (which is build with total client side code, html/javascript), for creating Provider Hosted Add-in, please refer the following demo:

[Provider Hosted App in SharePoint Online using Visual Studio 2017 + Deploy Provider Hosted Add-in to Microsoft Azure](https://www.sharepointsky.com/provider-hosted-app-in-sharepoint-online/)